# Where to find printf formatting reference?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

Where is the *offline reference* of the format specifiers (e.g., `%i`, `%s`) which are supported by the Bash/system `printf` command? I've looked in `help printf`, `man 1 printf` and `man 3 printf` without luck.

`man 1 printf` mentions says it supports

> %%     a single %
>
> %b     ARGUMENT as a string with `\' escapes interpreted, except that octal escapes are of the form \0 or \0NNN
>
> and all C format specifications ending with one of diouxXfeEgGcs, with ARGUMENTs converted to proper type first.  Variable widths are handled.

The character list is useful, but doesn't explain the exact semantics of each format specification.

Comment: The `printf` entry in `man bash` refers to `man 1 printf` and contains additional format specifiers like `%b`, `%q` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the man page references the C format specifications, you may want to explore it to get the details. E.g. here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

If you insist on having the *offline reference*, you might want to install the corresponding man pages pack for C lib, so that you could see `man 3 printf`. This man page is a part of man-pages-2.39-15.el5 package on an old RHEL nearest to me.

Comment: I missed it in `man 3 printf` before - Format specifiers are called "conversion specifiers" there, and are not listed with the percent sign in front.

Comment: Just to make it explicit: the shell `printf` command supports only a subset of the specifiers detailed in `man 3 printf`.