# i/o format with printf in bash-shell

Tags: bash, shell, columns, printf

I am trying to output the results of my shell script using printf.
To keep the results aligned in column, I am using tab as:

```
printf "%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n" $i $est $var_m $jk $mst $var_M  $Tes >>tmp
```

But the problem is, for some cases, the results are bit long, as a output of say,

```
var_M=`echo "scale=8;(-1/$jk + (e(2*$jk)+1)/(e(2*$jk)-1))"|bc -l `
```

So, it will be better for me, if I can format print to the column, something like:

```
printf "%s *goto column 20* %s *go to column 30* " $i $est >>tmp
```

is this possible?

I have checked [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58856/where-to-find-printf-formatting-reference) and also the man pages, but failed to find it.
Is this possible?

NB: I do not have any special reason to stick to printf. so any other suitable command that can do the thing (easily) is also welcome.

**EDIT:** tried: `printf "%-2s %-8s\n" $i $est >>tmp`
which is not clearly working:

```
4.0 0.17169E-02
5. 0.17156E-02
10. 0.17129E-02
```

(The 2nd row/2nd column is not aligned, just like the case of list-formatted output)

Comment: 2 is not enough for "4.0", try with printf "%-20s %-20s\n" $i $est >>tmp

Comment: You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$i"` and `"$est"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf "%-20s %-30s" $i $est >>tmp
```